# Remove duplicate rows based on conditions from multiple columns (decreasing order) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, conditional-statements, plyr

I have a 3-columns data.frame (variables: `ID.A`, `ID.B`, `DISTANCE`). I would like to remove the duplicates under a condition: keeping the row with the smallest value in column 3.

It is the same problem than here :
[R, conditionally remove duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835284/r-conditionally-remove-duplicate-rows)
(Similar one: [Remove duplicates based on 2nd column condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962909/remove-duplicates-based-on-2nd-column-condition))

But, in my situation, there is second problem : I have to remove rows when the **couples** (`ID.A`, `ID.B`, `DISTANCE`) are duplicated, and not only when `ID.A` is duplicated.

I tried several things, such as:

```
df <- ddply(df, 1:3, function(df) return(df[df$DISTANCE==min(df$DISTANCE),]))
```

but it didn't work

Example :

This dataset

```
    id.a id.b dist
1    1    1   12
2    1    1   10
3    1    1   8
4    2    1   20
5    1    1   15
6    3    1   16
```

Should become:

```
    id.a id.b dist
3    1    1   8
4    2    1   20
6    3    1   16
```

Comment: this is a perfect job for `dplyr`, but your question doesn't make sense. What does "keep the smallest value in column 3" and "remove rows were triplets are duplicated" mean? If The triplet is duplicated then necessarily there is only one value in column 3? Am I missing something?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr

Comment: @Alex - i'm assuming OP means the couplet `ID.A / ID.B`, but they should clarify.

Comment: I added an example. @thelatermail you're right, it wasn't clear, it's couple ID.A / ID.B, with condition on column 3

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of one of the linked queries - you can just run an `order` operation first to get what you want `dat <- dat[do.call(order, dat),]; dat[!duplicated(dat[1:2]),]`

Comment: It's more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, and a suitable modification to [Remove duplicated rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
group_by(id.a, id.b) %>%
arrange(dist) %>% # in each group, arrange in ascending order by distance
filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: Why not use `distinct()`: `df %>% group_by(id.a, id.b) %>% arrange(dist) %>% distinct`

Comment: I don't know how to use `distinct`.

Comment: Well, I guess now you do :)

Comment: I find `distinct` rather confusing, as the helpfile doesn't really explain how it works with grouped data frames.

Comment: @Alex If the data frame is grouped, then `distinct` simply finds the distinct entries within each group.

Comment: Claus is correct. Maybe if you look at it this way: `df %>% arrange(dist) %>% distinct(id.a, id.b)`

Comment: @ClausWilke I don't think that is correct, unless you mean "find distinct entries within groups". I do not see why the following two should be equivalent: `df %>% distinct(id.a, id.b)` and `df %>% group_by(id.a, id.b) %>% distinct()`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré @alex `distinct()` with groups is indeed strange, and doesn't always behave as one would expect. Note that the documentation available through `?distinct` doesn't talk about grouping at all. Maybe `distinct` is not meant to be used on grouped variables after all.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of achieving the solution and retaining all the columns:

```
df %>% arrange(dist) %>% 
  distinct(id.a, id.b, .keep_all=TRUE)

#   id.a id.b dist
# 1    1    1    8
# 2    3    1   16
# 3    2    1   20
```